Using GiST Notation from LTREE Extension in Supabase Client
I'm working with the LTREE extension in my PostgreSQL database hosted on Supabase, and I need to utilize the GiST (Generalized Search Tree) notation provided by the extension. Specifically, I want to perform queries using operators such as <, >=, @>, etc...
I'm aware that I can create custom functions and call them using supabase.rpc(fn), but this approach is redundant. Is there a way to execute custom SQL queries directly from the Supabase JavaScript client?
I've explored the Supabase documentation and haven't found a straightforward solution for this. Any guidance on how to use GiST notation with LTREE extension in Supabase client would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
